# Getting an error while starting Apache Kylin. Using Hadoop-2.6.0, Hbase-0.98, hive-0.14 Versions

Tags: apache

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar (No
>   such file or directory)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
Modify $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh
Disable the loop:
#for f in $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar; do
#  if [ "$HADOOP_CLASSPATH" ]; then
#    export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:$f
#  else
#    export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$f
#  fi
#done
```

Answer (score 0):

Minimal Hadoop Versions required for Apache kylin installation

```
Hadoop: 2.7+
Hive: 0.13 - 1.2.1+
HBase: 0.98 - 0.99, 1.1+
JDK: 1.7+
```

check with this official link
http://kylin.apache.org/docs21/install/hadoop_env.html